# Php outputing Json encoded data from mysql database

Tags: php

I am just having an error in my output through my php file. I believe it is an easy fix.
While it should be displaying data it is displaying this.

```
[{"first_name":"first_name","mobile_phone":"mobile_phone"},`
```

and here is my php file. Really hope this is a simple fix. Thanks

```
   <?php

    function connect() {


        // Connecting to mysql database
        $con = mysql_connect(private);

        // Selecing database
        $db = mysql_select_db("intraweb_db") or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

        // returing connection cursor
        return $con;
    }




//end of connect to db
connect();

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT 'first_name', 'mobile_phone' FROM `admin_contacts`");

$output = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $output[]=$r;

}
echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

Awesome ;) thank you guys. got it working

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated, consider using `mysqli` or `PDO`. Can you please use `print_r($output)` before the `json_encode` function and update us - what's the output.

Comment: Use backticks or no quotes for your column names, for one thing.

Comment: Funny how you think that if `mysql_select_db()` dies it can die again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing wrong in your query. don't use single or double quote in your column name.

**Try this:**

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT first_name,mobile_phone FROM `admin_contacts`");
$output = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $output[]=$r;    
}
echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

You also need to change in this line:

```
$db = mysql_select_db("intraweb_db") or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());
```

to

```
$db = mysql_select_db("intraweb_db") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: To elaborate, the single quotes around `'first_name'` and `'mobile_phone'` makes mysql return them as strings, rather than the values in the columns with those names. (You should use backticks for that)

Comment: @user3169485 : did you try this? if it worked then accept an answer.